# Controlling file access permission

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

We have around 100 user accounts on a Linux server, and 20 of them belong to my ITOp team. I want to allow my team user accounts to only view my files in a subdirectory directly under my /home directory. How can I control the file access permissions for these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the 20 users in the ITOp team in the same `group`?

If not, create a non-system group (`man addgroup`), and add the users to the group. Add yourself to the group, as well.

Change (`man chmod`) the permission of the directory to allow group read and execute (`rwxr-x---` ).

Use `chown` (`man chown`) to change the group of the directory and the files you want to share to the group in paragraph 1.

Use `chmod` to change the file permissions to allow group read (`rwxr-----`).

Ensure the users can see the shared directory, by allowing group read access to your `$HOME` directory.

Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works!